# ScrollViewer won't scroll on empty parts of the Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, mousewheel

I have a Grid with a `ScrollViewer` around it:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I the code-behind I fill this Grid with a dynamic amount of `RowDefinitions`. In the first column, I always put a `TextBlock` displaying a certain time of day (08:00, 08:10, ...):

http://www.youth-area.ch/users/finnland/times.png

My problem now is the scolling. When I mousescroll with my **cursor over the textblocks**, it scrolls **without a problem**. But when I place my cursoer over the **empty part of the grid** (right side), it **won't scroll**.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might just have to set a background on your Grid?